# Configuration of MQ with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

Please provide your suggestion for following statement:

I need to do a MQ Websphere performance testing. The MQ's are installed on a remote machine.
I need to configure with JMeter and need to pass data in format of XML and CSV files to MQ.
JMeter is installed on my local machine.
I searched online for configurations, where I found following options of configuring it:

1. JMS Point-to-Point sampler.
2. JSR223 Sampler
3. JMS Publisher/Subscriber

The current MQ which I have, has following configuration data:

“host name” 
“service port” 
“channel name” 
“queue manager name” 
“queue name”
“userid” and “password”

Could any one please suggest the best possible way of configuring MQ and sending the test data files.
Do I have to install the MQ on my local machine too? Also, kindly provide a link/list of necessary jar files required for the same.

Note: JMeter version is 3.0(r1743807) and IBM MQ Websphere version is : 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe the only way is [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler).
2. You can obtain the necessary MQ Client JAR files from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744#1). Once done copy them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). If you really want/have to continue with JMeter 3.1 you will also need [`groovy-all.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all)
3. If you're looking for some sample code check out [Running the MQPubSubApiSample Java sample](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024240_.htm) and/or [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)
4. According to JMeter Best Practices you [should always stick to the latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to JMeter 4.0 (or whatever version is available on [JMeter Downloads Page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)